# What is going on with my tag badge tracking statistics?

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

I was fiddling around with my tracking stats under my user summary, and here is what my [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4) tag shows as my progress:

[image: Fallout-4 tag before clicking cog]

However, this doesn't correspond to both my tag score and when I click the cog wheel to the left of the tag in that picture above as shown here:

[image: Fallout-4 tag after clicking cog]

What is going on here?  I know that sometimes the statistics can be delayed by sometime, but I haven't answered a Fallout 4 question in a while.

Comment: I took a quick look at your profile and the second picture reflects the correct stats. Not sure what's going on, but disregard that first one, I guess.

Comment: I used to run across this problem, selecting a different tag badge for tracking and going back fixed it always for me.

Comment: @user3.14159265359 hmm that did work.  I wonder if it was a caching issue with browser or something.  I don't know if you want to post that as an answer.  I mean it fixed it, but doesn't explain why that happened.  Seems a little buggy...

Comment: @TimmyJim at a second check, clicking to track the tag badge you already are tracking works too. It seems it's a issue in tag badge updating. I'll add an answer in a while, if anybody doesn't come with an explanation for the issue.